# How do I store all the ascii characters in C?

Tags: c, ascii

```
for (i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    ascii_characters[i] = x;
    x++;
}

for (i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    printf("%c\n", ascii_characters[i]);
}
```

I want to store all the alphabets in my array.

What I've done in my code is I've stored all the ascii values between 65 to 122.
So I've stored all my values in my array. But I want to skip the values between 91 to 96.

Comment: "Code screen shot". How to not ask a question. Welcome to stackoverflow, by the way. You'd want to edit your question adding the code in the post instead of an image.

Comment: How is skipping the values from 91 to 96 consistent with "store all the ascii characters"?  For that matter, how is skipping the characters with codes less than 65 or from 123 to 127 consistent with that?

Comment: Do you know the function `isalpha`? It could help you: [man isalpha](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isalnum)

Comment: `ascii_characters[0] = 65; ascii_characters[1] = 66; /* ... */ ascii_characters[25] = 90; ascii_characters[26] = 97; /* ... */ ascii_characters[51] = 122;`

Comment: `char alphabet[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";`

Comment: +1 @JohnBode ... but that does not work if the computer running the program has a strange encoding like EBCDIC :-)

Comment: @pmg: The OP did specifically mention ASCII.  Also, based on my understanding of the question, the OP is interested in storing only alphabetic characters, and my solution should satisfy that requirement regardless of encoding.  If the OP is relying on those encoding values being *sequential* within the array, then yeah, that won't work with EBCDIC, but again, he specifically mentioned ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

```
int i = 0;
char c;
for (c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; c++) {
    ascii_characters[i++] = c;
} 

for (c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    ascii_characters[i++] = c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do is store the upper case and lower case letters, you need to separately check the letter each time you increment it.  If you start at `A`, once you increment past `Z` you want to just straight to `a`.

```
char x = 'A';
for (i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    ascii_characters[i] = x;
    if (x == 'Z') {
        x = 'a';
    } else {
        x++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for clarifying my doubt.